# Does SageMaker built-in LightGBM algorithm support distributed training?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, lightgbm, distributed-training, amazon-machine-learning

Does  **Amazon SageMaker built-in LightGBM** algorithm support **distributed training**?

I use Databricks for distributed training of LightGBM today. If SageMaker built-in LightGBM supports distributed training, I would consider migrating to SageMaker. It is not clear in the Amazon SageMaker's built-in [LightGBM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/lightgbm.html)'s documentation on whether it supports distributed training.

Thanks very much for any suggestion or clarification on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the LightGBM section of SageMaker documentation and there are no references that it supports distributed training. One of the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/lightgbm.html) uses single instance type. Also looked at lightGBM documentation [here](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parallel-Learning-Guide.html) . Here are the parameters that you need to specify

tree_learner=your_parallel_algorithm,

num_machines=your_num_machines,

Given I couldnt find any reference of above in SageMaker documentation, I assume its not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Currently SageMaker LightGBM doesn't support distributed training.

Comment: Do you have any documentation which support your answer?

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-built-in-lightgbm-now-offers-distributed-training-using-dask/

SageMaker LightGBM algorithm offers distributed training using the Dask framework for both tabular classification and regression tasks.